# I need a binary comparison tool for Win/Linux

Tags: linux, windows, binary, comparison

First of all, I don't need a textual comparison so Beyond Compare doesn't do what I need.

I'm looking for a util that can report on the differences between two files, at the byte level.  Bare minimum is the need to see the percentage change in the file, or a report on affected bytes/sectors.

Is there anything available to save me the trouble of doing this myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [VBinDiff](http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/).  I haven't used it, but it probably does what you want.

Comment: I use vbindiff. The interface is awful, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on what exactly is contained in the file, but here's a quick one:

```
hexdump file1 > file1.tmp
hexdump file2 > file2.tmp
diff file1.tmp file2.tmp
```

Since 16 bytes are typically reported on each line, this won't technically give you a count of the bytes changed, but will give you a rough idea where in the file changes have occurred.

Answer (score 1):

[UltraCompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultracompare.html) is the best for binary comparison. It has a smart comparator that is really useful.

Comment: I wonder if there is some other tool to offer ultracompare smart binary compare mode.... since ultracompare is not free nor opensource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xdelta](http://xdelta.org/). This is open source binary diff tool that you can use then to make binary patches, but I think it also gives the information about differences found.

Answer (score 1):

ECMerge recently introduced a [binary differ](http://www.elliecomputing.com), it can compare files of several giga bytes (the limit is somewhere above the *tera* byte). it works on linux, windows, mac os x and solaris.
it gives you byte by byte or block per block statistics.

You can parameter synchronization window (if desired) and minimal match.

Comment: Seems nice and lots of features. not freeware

Answer (score 0):

There's [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html) available for windows.  Here's a [page](http://www.araxis.com/merge/topic_comparing_binary_files.html) that describes their binary comparison feature.