# Is there any open source binary differ?

Tags: diff

From time to time, I need to compare files binarily, but is there any open source tool that can do this?

[UltraCompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultracompare.html) can, but it's a commercial product.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98693/i-need-a-binary-comparison-tool-for-win-linux) for a similar question

Comment: thank you folks, VBinDiff does the job pretty well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an open-source product called [VBinDiff](http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/) that I found in a search, but I don't have any direct experience with it.  It appears to be cross-platform (Linux and Windows) and has packages for the binaries and source.  Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

[bsdiff](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdiff&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%205.5-RELEASE) and [xdelta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdelta) are two that immediately come to mind.

Comment: How is xdelta useful in this context? It supposedly does not generate human readable output.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Where did you get the idea that the output had to be human readable?

Answer (score 4):

GNU [diffutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/) comes with a program called `cmp` that will tell you the first offset at which two binary files differ.  Unfortunately, it does little more than that.

Alternatively, you could hexdump each file and pipe it into your favorite text diff tool:

```
diff <(hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x\n"' binfile1) <(hexdump -v '1/1 "%02x\n"' binfile2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - just wanted to add that the above `hexdump` form causes a display of one byte per line; if you want to show the same byte as both byte value and a character on a single line, an additional `-e` statement should be included for each `hexdump` - so ...

Comment: ... the above becomes: `diff <(hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%_p "' -e '1/1 "%02x\n"' binfile1) <(hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%_p "' -e '1/1 "%02x\n"' binfile2)`

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, I'd never run across cmp or hexdump before.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion *must* know how. It supports incremental change recording for binary objects.

Worst case you could look at their source base...

Answer (score 0):

The standard GNU [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) shows if two files differ. You might want to look into [xdelta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdelta) for tracking changes (probably what SCM tools use).

To see changes in the files you could [hexdump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump) both files and just diff them, I suppose.